# Better names for single component and composite component

Tags: nouns, synonyms

We are developing an equipment system which basically tracks every single component used in bigger structures for a certain industry. We are distinguishing between single components and composite components.

So for example, a firetruck in our system is composed of other components, e.g water pump, ladder etc.

Any suggestions to better names for these two types of components?

Thanks

Comment: The corresponding adjective for *composite* is **simple**, rather than *single*.

Comment: See: http://www.synonyms.net/antonyms/composite

Comment: Not a very helpful answer, but the composite design pattern uses the term "component" for what you are describing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern#Structure When it's a component that has sub-components, it's called a "composite". That's definitely not intuitive, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the word "assembly" in place of "composite component". As long as you make the definition clear in this context, it seems to me to be a reasonable way of expressing it.

Answer (score 0):

Singular item = component
Item created from multiple components = construct

That's how I would identify them, at least.  Especially if you are tracking the components and then what components a construct is assembled from.